# More than one app has same URL Identifier for custom URL application

Tags: ios

I have used a custom URL scheme in my application to open it from another application (which may be my own). Suppose more than one application in App Store may have the same URL Identifier I used. If user has two applications with same URL scheme, what will open? Will custom URL application be approved by Apple?

Answer (score 15):

Custom URL apps are accepted by Apple. However if multiple apps on the device have registered same URL scheme then the behavior is undefined. From [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html), "If multiple third-party applications register to handle the same URL scheme, it is undefined as to which of the applications is picked to handle URLs of that type."

Comment: @eggie5, it is clearly stated by Apple that the behavior is undefined. So you can't tell exactly what will happen.

Comment: @tasknoor I think "clearly stated" and apple saying "undefined" is rather an oxymoron. What happends? Does it raise an error? Does the phone shut-down, does the stock market crash???

Comment: I thought undefined means you can't tell which application will run. If multiple app has same URL then one of them will be picked. Which one? I can't tell as Apple has not specified their algorithm and I have not worked for Apple and thus I haven't seen the code.

Comment: yeah I think it's a cop-out for everyone to say it's "undefined". Does 1 app or the other run? Do none of them? ...

Comment: @eggie5 This is an old question but that "undefined" part is actually defined and i wanted to share it. The last installed application will be opened.

Comment: @frankish, where this is defined? Can you please point to the appropriate doc? Yes, its a very old question and things could have changed later.

Comment: I defined it (: I am using this (same identifier etc) since 2009 for 2 versions of my app (paid & free). I have experienced the behaviour and it never changed since 4 years. As both free and paid app won't be living together at the same time on many users, this was not a problem for anyone. (If they do, only one of them works. No errors or rejections)

Comment: An update, this behavior has changed on iOS 7. Now the first installed app will open, but will fail often. Tested on device. See my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: First app to register URL will sometimes open but it will fail to open often. Other times second app to register will open but fail often. Basically it fails a lot and really is "undefined". Use http://handleopenurl.com/ to avoid.

Long Answer:

I created two apps, FirstApp and SecondApp, and registered the same URL `testURL` for both.

I loaded FirstApp and the URL worked as expected, opening the app.

I then loaded SecondApp and the dreaded undefined behavior started occurring. Currently, under iOS 7, if two apps have the same custom URL registered it pops up a modal asking

> Open this page in "Name of First App"?

When you tap the Open option it fails, and nothing happens. If you tap or enter the link again the first app installed with that URL, in our case FirstApp, will launch.

So in effect, the second app to register never gets opened, and the first app fails every two URL calls. No ideal behavior.

What makes it even worse is I deleted both apps and then switched the order I installed them and the results are not consistent. Sometimes it is one app, then on reloading both apps it is the other. The behavior really is "undefined".

Best practice is to use http://handleopenurl.com/ to see what URLs have been registered and chose one that will not conflict with other apps. You can't "steal" another URL because you can't be sure your app will open and not the other app.

Answer (score -1):

this may be your answer that you are finding

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

By reading this article It may be possible that apple can reject your application, still you can read the guide line provided by apple. 
Thanks